# Planning heusristic for my scout camp

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I am planning a scout camp and need to automated the planning.

I have a set of scouts that need to be grouped in tents of certain capacity, subject to many constraints.

Amongst the constraints:

- The availability of the tent (they are set and unset throughout the summer)
- The availability of the scout
- The color of the tent
- The color preferred by the scout
- etc.

I have over 500 scouts and around 20 tents.

I am searching for a good algorithm to approach this problem.
I can model it as a MILP, but it is both too large to be solved efficiently, and fails to give approximate solutions, which basically makes it a no-go.

Any suggestion on what I should be looking at? Tabu? Simulated annealing? Other heuristics?

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'fails to give approximate solutions': (I) what is the integrality gap, after how much Cpu time (II) what variables are you using (III) do you have big M variables? and (IV) which solver are you using? Any heuristic approach would require a dedicated algorithm.

Comment: Any chance you could post the MIP model?

Comment: Managed to solve some instances with Neos (one of the solvers used by...). I'll post an instance in the coming days.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you say that there are many constraints then an MILP would be the best way to go about it. However, if the constraints that you mentioned are the only ones, then following approach can be thought of.

Model this as a transportation problem.

First you filter out the unavailable tents and unavailable scouts.

For each color of tent, calculate the total capacity = summation( tentCapacity ) for each color tent.
These colors shall be destinations.

Group the students according to their preferred color for tents. These shall be sources.

In the source/destination matrix, put the cost of transporting a student to its preferred color tent as zero, and cost of other colors as 1.

IMO this can be solved using transportation problem solving technique: http://www.me.utexas.edu/~jensen/models/network/net8.html

EDIT: The transportation problem formulation described above is a very general approach in which you can handle multiple preferences of different priorities. If each scout has just a single preference then I think the problem is trivial, just first fill up all the preferred colored tents, and distribute the remaining scouts to other non-preferred tents.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to [hospital bed planning](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#pas) (and prison bed allocation and hotel room allocation for that matter). Basically, the patients are scouts, the beds are sleeping bags and the rooms are tents. Look for implementations of INRC2011, such as [this one](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/pas/solver/patientAdmissionScheduleScoreRules.drl#L46):

[image]

*Simulated Annealing*, *Tabu Search* and *Late Acceptance* all work well on hospital bed planning. In general, **Late Acceptance** wins in [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/)'s benchmarks currently for that use case.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey, will have a look at OptaPlanner.